# Deprecation warning when using `rake db:seed`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rolify

I'm having a `DEPRECATION WARNING` when using `rake db:seed`

```
This dynamic method is deprecated.
```

This happens on `user.add_role :admin` of the block below:

```
user = User.find_or_create_by(email: ENV['ADMIN_EMAIL'].dup) do |u| 
  u.password = ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD'].dup
  u.password_confirmation = ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD'].dup
end
puts 'user: ' << user.email
user.add_role :admin
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save!
```

I have already cleaned the code for a `find_or_create_by_email` warning, but I cannot find the answer for the `add_role`.

Comment: I don't think this deprecation warning is coming from cancan.  You can probably remove the cancan tag from this question.  Where is `add_role` defined?

Comment: I cannot find this method in my code. My app is based on a github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan but this template is for Rails 3.x and I'm on 4. I think it's a helper given in devise or in rolify, I'm going to check in the sources of those gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was due to the version of rolify. It's been fixed with 3.2 for me [cf](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/183)